# In align environment, put word at left margin and still align equations with &?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

In an `align` environment, how can I put a word such as "Now" or "And" at the left margin and still align equations on that line and subsequent lines with `&`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `flalign` environment; another option (if the text must appear between two parts of the math expression) could be to use the `\intertext` command; in the following example I used `\rlap` inside `flalign*` to box the text using a zero width box, thus achieving a similar horizontal alignment to that of `align*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\Text{% jut to generate filler text for the example
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.}

\begin{document}

\Text
\begin{flalign*}
&& a &= b  & \\
\rlap{and} && &= c & \\
\rlap{and} && &= d. & \\
\end{flalign*}
\Text
\begin{align*}
a &= b  \\
 &= c 
\intertext{and} 
&= d.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The vertical space introduced by the `\intertext` command from `amsmath` often seems excessive; the `mathtools` package offers `\shortintertext` to alleviate this situation.

Comment: For visual appearance (horizontal alignment) similar to `align*`, I would use `\text{\rlap{and}}` in `flalign*`.

Comment: `\rlap{and}` is enough, no need for `\text`